# Android: mkdir returns false in system service

Tags: android, mkdir

when i use mkdir inside an Android system service, it returns false.
Following is the simple code:

```
try{
    File dir = new File(filePath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        boolean rst = dir.mkdirs();
        if (rst == false) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create dir:" + filePath); // hits this code
        }
    }
}
```

Same code works fine when I run from an Android application.
Has anybody worked on Android system service ?
Any idea why mkdir function returns false inside system service ?
Thanks.

Comment: pls post your file path !!what is the value in filepath ??

Comment: I think system service is not allowed to create directories.